# How do you set an ETA for a task in GAE's task engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run a task an hour in the future.  Here's what I'm doing, doesn't seem to work.

```
import static com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.TaskOptions.Builder.*;


Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(new Date()); 
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1); 
cal.getTime(); 

Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
queue.add(withUrl("/task/doMyThing").param("userId", userId).header("X-AppEngine-TaskETA", cal.getTime().getTime()+""));
```

-edit

OK then a little more clarification: When someone hits my service I want to call a Java method exactly an hour after they hit the service.   I assumed the task queue was the best way to do that on App Engine. I thought the queue would not execute that task unless the ETA had passed.   If I'm approaching this the wrong way and there's a better way to accomplish it please let me know.

-edit again

Thanks for the answers, for the record here's what I did:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
queue.add(withUrl("/task/sendReminder").param("userId", userId).countdownMillis(120000));
```

Comment: ETA stands for estimated time of arrival. I only mention this because it seems like you are trying to set a task for a future time and that would not be considered ETA. So are you trying to just set up a task to execute in an hour instead of get an ETA on the current task or future task?

Comment: Well, arguably, pedantically, since the implementation is to send a request to the server that happens to execute the task desired, the "ETA" of that request is what you're actually specifying here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done what you're trying to do but in python. I think the header you're trying to set is one that appengine sets when it starts a task from the queue and not necessarily one that you set when you're creating the task. I think you're looking for [countdownMillis](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#countdownMillis%28long%29) with a value of 3600000.

Comment: Are there any known limitation on countdownMillis?  For example, could it be set to 25 hours from now?  I ask because I'm processing my task in a module which Google allows to run for 24 hours at most.  If put the task on the queue and specify for it to run in 25 hours, is the module still considered to be running?  Will my task get shut down?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky, time period in countdownMillis has to be less than 30 days. About the 24 hour deadline for module, it probably means that there is no deadline and the module instance continues to run unless you stop it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The java 
 [Timer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) is the one to investigate.

If you want to execute the task after an hour but as you mentioned 
"task an hour in the future" seems unclear

Comment: Ok thanks, I added a bit more to my initial question.  Please let me know if that changes your answer at all.

Comment: Yes you can use the timer object or you can use multi threading [a bit Advanced] [a timer usage example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html).  I'd have one thread pull objects from the `DelayQueue` continuously and hand them off to a cached thread pool to execute them as soon as possible, rather than use a `Timer`.

`DelayQueue` will block until the waiting period for the next item has expired.  You can control when the objects can be removed from the queue by setting their delay period prior to adding them to the queue to ensure they stay in the queue for the alotted time.

Using a cached thread pool will ensure that each task gets executed as soon as it comes off the queue as well as minimize initialization time/space by reusing threads instead of initializing new ones every time a task gets pulled off the queue.

Comment: It seems like you should only use DelayQueue if your FIFO ConcurrentLinkedQueue  is too full of threads and you need to push some of them off as delayed, right?

Comment: Not sure I follow you.  `DelayQueue` is basically a priority queue that sorts its items by their expected release time and blocks until the next item's delay expires - so you'd use it whenever you want that kind of functionality.  Seems perfect for @Pickles' situation to me when coupled with a cached thread pool.  The alternative would be to spawn a new thread that waited an hour before executing the task, but what happens if a million of those delayed calls occur before the first got executed?  It'd take 4GB of stack space to spawn that many threads before the first task ever got executed.