# How use Task Queue to do something at a later time?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

According to [this Google article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors), 
"You can also use the Task Queue to do the write at a later time, which has the added benefit that the Task Queue automatically retries failures."

Suppose I'm trying to keep my daily spend on Google App Engine under a certain budget.  Let's say I start to detect I'm getting low on quota for the day so I want to reschedule the work for tomorrow.  It would be great to use Task Queues for this instead of Cron jobs because the initiation of the work and the rescheduling of the work can be handled pretty similarly.

How do I put a task on the Task Queue and specify that it should not begin until a particular time?  I can see how I might use [RetryOptions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/RetryOptions) to get part of what I want, namely to delay the work.  But RetryOptions doesn't seem to provide a way to specify not to retry until 24 hours have passed since "now" or don't retry until midnight.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can use [`TaskOptions.countdownMillis(long)`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#countdownMillis(long)) to specify how long to wait before executing the task.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "later time", in the sense that your application doesn't stop to wait for your write to go through, so you work in parallel.

If you want to control WHEN to start a cleanup or something similar, look into [CRON jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron)

Comment: Thanks @Patrice but what do you think of using [`TaskOptions.countdownMillis(long)`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions#countdownMillis(long))

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem, but I think you'll have more  control with a CRON, I don't know if the countdown literally STOPS the task, or simply makes it wait. If it makes it wait, you have a time limit that might become a problem

Comment: I'm interpreting the countdown as a time to wait until STARTING the task.  But you're saying something about STOPPING the task.  Could you explain what you mean?  Many thanks.

Comment: Well task queues are limited in time (to an hour, unless you push them to a module). If your countdown is an actual countdown to start the task, then I don't see why it would be a problem. If it starts the task but "halts" it, then the 1-hour time limit would still apply. I'm not sure of the exact behavior to be honest, but I think it's something worth being aware of

Comment: Thanks Patrice, that's a really helpful potential issue for me to be aware of.  I am running in a module but the same issue may apply since modules can only run for up to 24 hours.  If I have a use case where I need to delay for a couple of days, it might not work.

Comment: While researching Patrice's point, I posted this comment for more advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949418/how-do-you-set-an-eta-for-a-task-in-gaes-task-engine/16952671#comment43103512_16952671